# Decode weird hex value to string in python

Tags: python, hex, decode

I have a weird hex value that's supposed to be a mapped string.
I tried removing unnecessary `0` when there are like with `000000070000000b` that supposed to be `7b` but for some reason I still get weird chars

Examples: (I can only show part of the json since it has private info)

of what I need to get:

`{"BotBehavior": {"type": 2, "score": 304, "score_timestamp": 1623730836453, "score_metadata": {"scoreCount": "0"`

What I have:

`000000070000000b426f744265686176696f720000014500000004000000020000000400000130000000080000017a0de653e5000000f8000000060000000a73636f7265436f756e74`

I tried something like that: (please dont judge the code its only to test my idea XD)

```
def get_decoded_char(char):
    index = 0
    for byte in char:
        if byte == '0':
            index += 1
        else:
            return char[index:]


def get_decoded_string(string):
    string_index = 0
    decoded_string = ""
    while string_index <= len(string):
        if string[string_index] == '0':
            encoded_char = get_decoded_char(string[string_index: string_index + 8]) + get_decoded_char(
                string[string_index + 8: string_index + 16])
            decoded_string += bytearray.fromhex(encoded_char).decode()
            string_index += 16
        else:
            encoded_char = string[string_index: string_index + 2]
            decoded_string += bytearray.fromhex(encoded_char).decode()
            string_index += 2
    return decoded_string
```

Thanks for the help!

EDIT:
I've used the command: `sstabledump -d -t <my_file> > dump.json`

Comment: The data ``000000070000000b426f744265686176696f720000014500000004000000020000000400000130000000080000017a0de653e5000000f8000000060000000a73636f7265436f756e74`` is not a valid Python value. Is this a ``str``, ``bytes`` or something else?

Comment: I don't see how we could decode this without knowing the rules it was encoded with. From `000000070000000b426f744265686176696f72` you get `{BotBehavior` - the opening quote for the dict key is notably missing. But then what do we make of  the following sequence? I don't see any clear rules to follow.

Comment: Does your data *actually* contain JSON? Is this BSON perhaps? This appears to be a framed binary format, with a header giving the size of the next field – e.g. ``0000000400000002`` is "size 4 => content = ``00000002``" – and thus likely a columnar format. What makes you think ``000000070000000b`` is supposed to be ``7b``?

Comment: @tdelaney I have a command (sstabledump) that when I use a certain flag I get that json and for the other I get that string representing hex
Sadly I need to use the flag that gives me the hex so I need to figure out how I get the json from that hex. If I knew the rule for the encoding I wouldn't have to ask :)

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I think it supposed to be json but even if its BSON it gets weird after `000000070000000b426f744265686176696f72` I can't figure out why i can't get a proper value I tried: bson.json_utils.loads(bytearray.fromhex(bin_json)) but i still get an error

Comment: @EmaIl Look, there really isn't anything we can do at this point *without you helping us*. A binary format can be interpreted in a myriad of ways, and even having several complete samples of data and output are tough to dismantle. Having a single incomplete sample where the data does not even completely match the output (e.g. the data seems to be missing the inner keys and might be a list instead) makes it futile. If you got this data from a publicly available toolset, as your comment on ``sstabledump`` suggests, please include the actual command used in your question. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] If you cannot include either the exact command or the exact data or the exact output because of privacy concerns, please take a look at the [mcve] help page. Ideally, you would not share the exact situation anyway, but a smaller, representative, reproducible example – in which you can freely use non-sensitive dummy data.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I understand and thanks for trying to help!! I've added the command that I use. I didn't add it in the first place because I couldn't find anything that could assist but hope it would help!